# Why this simple scheduler does not work?

Tags: java, timer, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Am I doing anything wrong?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class CIScheduler {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        timerService.createTimer(1000, 5000, "myTimerInterval");
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer) {
        System.out.println("Current Time : " + new Date());
    }
}
```

Stack: JDK 8, Wildfly 10

Error LOG:

> 09:31:31,781 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 9) WFLYEJB0161:
>   Failed to reinstate timer 'config-api.config-api.CIScheduler'
>   (id=f571b03a-efa 9-467d-a9de-b17d88bf54c7) from its persistent state
>   09:31:31,783 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 9) WFLYEJB0022:
>   Error duri ng retrying timeout for timer:
>   [id=35f55f82-a982-43d8-bece-42cfc89debe8 timedObj
>   ectId=config-api.config-api.CIScheduler auto-timer?:false persistent
>   ?:true
>   timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@1eef0fd
>   init ialExpiration=Wed Jun 15 09:20:46 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in
>   milli sec)=5000 n extExpiration=Wed Jun 15 09:31:36 BRT 2016
>   timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT info=myTimer Interval]:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ja
>   va.lang.ClassCastException@1da01b2

Samples extracted from: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/ejb3/timer/ejb-timer-service-example/

**UPDATE:** I cleaned the data and tmp folder and the error log changed to:

> 09:49:42,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 2) WFLYEJB0021:
>   Timer: [id
>   =26b74afb-625d-4007-a786-1c0caa92a70b timedObjectId=configuracao-api.config-api.CIScheduler
>   auto-timer?:false persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.e
>   jb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@1b701e2 initialExpiration=Wed Jun 15
>   09:49:37 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=5000
>   nextExpiration=Wed Jun 15 09:49:47 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT
>   info=myTimerInterval] will be retried 09:49:42,179 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 2) WFLYEJB0023: Retrying t imeout
>   for timer: [id=26b74afb-625d-4007-a786-1c0caa92a70b
>   timedObjectId=config-api.config-api.CIScheduler
>   auto-timer?:false persistent?:true timerS
>   ervice=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@1b701e2
>   initialExpiration
>   =Wed Jun 15 09:49:37 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=5000 nextExpiration
>   =Wed Jun 15 09:49:47 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT info=myTimerInterval] 09:49:42,181 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB
>   default - 2) WFLYEJB0022: Error duri ng retrying timeout for timer:
>   [id=26b74afb-625d-4007-a786-1c0caa92a70b timedObj
>   ectId=config-api.config-api.CIScheduler auto-timer?:false
>   persistent ?:true
>   timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@1b701e2
>   init ialExpiration=Wed Jun 15 09:49:37 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in
>   milli sec)=5000 n extExpiration=Wed Jun 15 09:49:47 BRT 2016
>   timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT info=myTimer Interval]:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument
>   type mismatch
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInt
>   erceptor.java:187)
>   .......

Comment: I would clean up the deploy directory - removing old temp and work directories - first (I assume you are working with a test installation, not in production). Restarting the domain could help.

Comment: Thanks dude, I did it and the log error changed, I put it on the question. @mjn

Comment: Using the feature @Schedule(second="*", minute="*", hour="*") works fine..  I will try on the wildfly 8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method annotated with @Timeout is only allowed to have an argument from type javax.ejb.Timer. You inadvertently imported Timer from the util package (java.util.Timer). If you fix the import, the timer should work like a charm :).

Comment: you're right, these automatic ide importing played me a trick. I did it and works well, thanks dude!

Answer (score 8):

To solve that problem, you must do some steps:

1. Undeploy your war or jar or ear which has the timer service using `@Schedule`
2. Go to this path on your wildfly server: `wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/data/timer-service-data/`
   and remove your content, something like this: `eSocialWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.eSocialWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ESocialTimer`.
3. Deploy your war or jar or ear again and smile!

As result, you never see this message again, unless if you change something in your timer `@Schedule`:

```
[org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYEJB0161: Failed to reinstate timer 'eSocialWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.eSocialWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ESocialTimer'
```